# Rails- when doing a multiple condition search, how to eliminate the column with nil value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A car has three attributes, "model", "location", "status". I want to search cars according these three conditions. First, I thought I could use

```
 Car.where(model: params[:car][:model], location: params[:car][:location], status: params[:car][:status])
```

However, I do not know how to eliminate the column with nil value. For example, if I do not input model which means params[:car][:model] = nil, it would actually do `select * from car where model = null and status = ? and location = ?`
However, what I want is `select * from car where location= ? and status = ?`. How could I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to slice out the parameters you want:

```
# `.fetch(:car, {})` prevents a nil error if the key is not present in the params.
params.fetch(:car, {}).permit(:location, :status, :model)
# or if `params[:car]` is required.
params.require(:car).permit(:location, :status, :model)
```

Then use [`Hash#compact`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact) which returns a new hash with nil values removed:

```
irb(main):008:0> {"location"=>1, "status"=>nil, "model"=>"Ford Model T"}.compact
=> {"location"=>1, "model"=>"Ford Model T"}
```

Altogether:

```
Car.where(params.fetch(:car, {}).slice(:location, :status, :model).compact)
```

Comment: If you are ever literally copying a list of hash keys you are doing it wrong. Ruby and especially Rails has tons of methods for blacklisting, whitelisting and merging hashes.